# How to measure road width from road survey photographs with GPS location

Tags: python, opencv

I realise that the following question is very broad and contains no code yet. The reason is that I've not been able to find any examples in how to solve the following.

I have been tasked to find a solution to determine the road width within each photograph that will be taken from a Logitech C920 Web Camera, attached to a G-Star IV GPS receiver. Would it be possible to use OpenCV to determine the road with within each image that will be taken every 10 meters? I've considered placing a known reference scale on the hood of the car that can be used afterwards to determine the actual width of the road in relation to the pixels in the image. What I have not been able to determine yet, is at which location within the image to measure the road width, and how to estimate the amount of distortion based on the distance away from the camera to get an accurate measurement. If anyone has developed a methodology using OpenCV to calculate road widths, I'd appreciate the any input.

We are open to using alternative camera if need be, to achieve the following.

[image]

Example photograph from Logitech Web Camera.

Note that the majority of the roads that will be surveyed will be asphalt and will have road markings for lanes.

Comment: This is a very broad and high level question, whereas this forum is for specific programming questions. You seem to have a more complicated problem than you likely think.. Personally, I'd use geometry to your favor, and try to mount the camera facing downwards to take parallax out of the equation. This would require the camera to be a very wide angle, and mounted relatively high up. It will require calibration to correct for lens distortion, and to determine the accurate focal length (not published by logitech)

Comment: I can only agree with @Aaron. Having done some work with OpenCV, the better your input is, the easier the processing gets. With this setup, you will run into severe problems. Especially since you can see the left side of the road fairly detailed, but the right hand side stops at 3/4 of the top edge of the frame. But OpenCV has no method called ``determineRoadWidth()``. You will have to do quite a lot of processing. I assume the video is already captured, right?

Comment: @Aaron. The images haven't as of yet been captured. The camera and gps that I mentioned is what is currently being used by the survey company that is performing a visual road condition assessment. We are looking to see if we can use the images that they capture to determine the road widths. I realise that the question is very broad, its just that I wasn't able to find any examples or methodology (code) that would solve the problem.

Comment: What about just using google maps? are the roads in question new? there are other satellite based survey options as well that might cost some money, but would be more recent. If you could get a drone to fly over the area, VisualSFM has a large-ish community around land surveying, and I've run across posts where people have used the likes of a dji drone to get pretty good results over areas many acres in size.

Comment: @PeterWilson Do you need the road width to determine where the drivable paths are?